# Acceptable alternatives to 'in petto'

Tags: word-usage

The following sentence is from an article in *Cicero*:

> Die SPD sollte froh sein, nach einem desolaten Wahlergebnis bei der
>   Bundestagswahl noch eine Frau **im Petto** zu haben, deren ganzes
>   politisches Leben Vorbereitung auf diese große Aufgabe war.
>   [Source](https://www.cicero.de/innenpolitik/andrea-nahles-spd-parteitag-parteivorsitz)

According to Duden and my Collins Klett German-English dictionary, the expression should be *in petto*. But a simple Google search returns results for *in Petto* and *im petto*, as well as *im Petto* as in the *Cicero* article.

Are any of these alternatives to Duden's *in petto* acceptable?

Comment: For me **im Petto** is simply wrong.

Comment: Tip: Use the Ngram viewer to search for real occurrence: https://books.google.com/ngrams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Etwas *in petto* haben**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/in%20petto)

This fixed phrase was derived from Italian *in petto*. From the *Etymologisches Wörterbuch nach Pfeifer* we read that it was first used in the context from the *ultra vires* of the pope to hold back the name of a new cardinal:

> geht auf die Befugnis des Papstes zurück, den Namen eines neuen Kardinals zunächst für sich (**in petto**) zu behalten und erst später bekanntzugeben.

The [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/in%20petto) lists many quotes from a variety of different sources where we can find *in petto* as the correct version. The error from the Cicero source may have been overlooked by the editor.

Because of the etymology a 100% identical alternative to *in petto* in the context of a personal position is not easy to find.

If we need to avoid *in petto* we may try the following similar phrases: *etwas in der Hinterhand halten, jemanden bereit halten, eine Alternative verfügbar haben, etwas in der Pipeline haben (I would not use this on people)*.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is "in petto", not "im petto". People often use it wrong. It's a bit like writing "ect." instead of "etc.".